# C# Excel 2010 programing

Tags: c#, excel

I am writing a program in C# for analysing a structure details in an earth quake.I have a lot of data and want to put them in a excel file.
I mean i need a function like this :

```
public void excel(int sheet_no,int row,int column,string value)
```

Is there any way to parse the text file and Put this data in Excel sheet ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Extreeeemely vague.  What are you trying to do, and what have you already done towards that end.

Comment: I have txt file with lots of numbers , over 1 milion detailed numbers , and want to put them in a excel file. that s all.How can i write them into excel file with C#?

Comment: Please have a look on following link: [ transfer data to an Excel workbook](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306023) [Convert the text file to Excel Format](http://www.geekinterview.com/talk/19527-convert-the-text-file-excel-format.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this :

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Workbooks workbooks;
_Workbook workbook;
_Workbook workbook2;
Sheets sheets;
_Worksheet worksheet;
app.Visible = false;
workbooks = app.Workbooks;
workbook = workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
sheets = workbook.Worksheets;
worksheet = (_Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(1);
worksheet.Cells[row, column] = value;
workbook.Saved = true;
workbook.SaveAs(output_file);
app.UserControl = false;
app.Quit();
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [ClosedXml](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/)

Code sample:

```
var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sample Sheet");
worksheet.Cell("A1").Value = "Hello World!";
workbook.SaveAs("HelloWorld.xlsx");
```

But if you are dealing with a lot of data, consider using a database like sqlserver.
It provides a lot of analysis tools.
You can connect it as a datasource to excel too.

Comment: I Tested this code and it worked but there was a problem.I couldnt create new excel file.i had to use one ready excel file.you can test it your self.

Comment: @Abadis, look at link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.add to create Workbooks and link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.open to Open Workbooks.  Basically you have to read up on Excel API and start understanding them. Sometimes MSDN doc provides code samples.

Answer (score 1):

For now, I am providing links for you to read @ [Excel Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/syyd7czh%28v=vs.80%29)  and code samples @ [Excel controls in ASP.net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/404688/Word-Excel-ActiveX-Controls-in-ASP-NET). If you're still confused, I may be able to find code samples from my projects or the Internet, which are not hard to find.

Look at link [Workbook Open (create) method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.add) to create Workbooks, and link [Workbook Open method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.open) to open Workbooks.